EmailMessage gets created using Email-to-case with more than 131072 characters in HTML Body? How is that Possible?
Salesforce max limit for HTMLBody field of EmailMessage object is - 131072 but I found that a customer sends an email with lot of tables in the body for which the case was created succesfully and also an related EmailMessage gets created with more than 131072 characters in HTMLBody.
How is it possible that an EmailMessage contains more than 131072 characters? Thanks for your answers.

How do you know how many characters it contains?
